# Avoid SharePoint Collection Admin from Accessing Certain Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, modern-experience, administration

I have created certain lists on SharePoint with only users can be able to see their entry. However, it turns out that the SharePoint Collection Admin can be able to view user's list entries.

Is there a way to avoid the SharePoint Collection Admin from viewing the entries of other user?

I have break the parents inheritance on the list but it does not help. Also, I did not set the SharePoint Collection Admin with any Permission Level at the list settings.

Thanks in advance and hope that anyone can give me some clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** possible in SharePoint.

> The SharePoint Site Collection Administrator cannot be locked out of any subsite, list, library, item, or page on the site.
>
> The permissions inheritance for any of these elements can be broken at any time, and permissions changed so that even users with Full Control rights have lesser permissions or even no permissions at all.
>
> In all cases the SharePoint Site Collection Administrator will always have full access to all of the elements and all of the data. This is especially handy when a site Owner accidentally deletes their own user account or group when creating custom permissions!

**Source**: [What Is a SharePoint Site Collection Administrator?](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/what-is-a-sharepoint-site-collection-administrator/)

---

The only possible solution is to update the site collection administrators so that they are populated with users that you do want to be able to access the whole site (i.e. the business/IT users who are the only ones who should have that access).

You can grant Full Control/Owners permissions to other users if needed.

---

**Update from comments**:

It is must to have at least one/primary site collection administrator on a site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it a must to have site collection administrator? Because we need a role to control all the group and user access but that guy should not be able to view certain list.

Comment: It is must to have at least one/primary site collection administrator on a site.

Answer (score 0):

Site Collection Admin is like a super admin having access to everything under the site.